# Select Drive Installion Screen

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, software-installation

In the select drive installation screen it says /dev/nvmw0n1-256Gb intel ssd but at the far right next to it, it says 174.0 GB does that mean how much free space I can use for Ubuntu?[image][image]

Comment: it's the actual physical size of the drive. expect to see this more and more as drives get faster and faster. more and more of the "marketed size" is size you'll never be able to tap into : https://www.tweakandtrick.com/2013/07/lost-storage-space.html http://www.ussscctv.com/harddrivesizecapacitiescalculator.aspx

Comment: If you could post a picture of your screen it would be worth a thousand words...

Comment: I uploaded it  now

Comment: I didn't found any occurrences of 174GB , can you point it out on picture?

Comment: Yes I uploaded the 2nd one at the far top right I’m confused on where I should install Ubuntu and how much I can give  because idk if I have 174 free or what

Answer (score 1):

The 256 GB marketed size is the physical storage capacity of the drive, is not the same as the actual available space once installed since the manufacturer use space on the disk itself to store drivers and other required software.

I find odd however, that the difference is that big, we are talking of ~81 GB of used space, do you have another OS or files installed in your SSD drive? if you want to use the entirety (or as much as possible) of the disk, you will have to format and delete any existing partitions.

Comment: Yes I have windows on it so would the 174 be what I have left  to use as my other partitions are very small

Comment: Yes, you can see from your screenshot that the NTFS file system used by Windows is around 254 GB, with around 84 Gb already used, Ubuntu can be installed next to Windows using NTFS and that's why  you can allocate space using the divider, after you select how much space you want to use the installer can take care of the rest, you will not lose Windows.